# integrate between range of changelist number in perforce command line

Tags: perl, perforce

perforce intergration between range of changelist

p4-64 integrate -c default $branch1 \@$chglist,\@$chglist $branch2 > changes.txt

Please correct the script If its wrong any where....please guide me

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

#use Mail::Sender;

if ($#ARGV < 2 )
{
printf "please enter source branch, target branch and changelistrange(eg: @10001,@100005)\n";
exit 0;
}

$branch1=$ARGV[0];
$branch2=$ARGV[1];
@branch_name=("$branch1", "$branch2");

$chglistrange=$ARGV[2];


print  $P4CLIENT;
system "(p4-64 info)" ;
#system "(p4-64 sync $branch1 )";
#system "(p4-64 sync $branch2 )";

sub verify_branches
{
  foreach(@branch_name)
  {
    print "You passed in branch $_\n";
           @array=`p4-64 branches -t -e $_`;
           print "@array\n";
  }
}
verify_branches

printf "start integration\n";
system ("p4-64 integ -v $branch1@$chglistrange $branch2 > changes.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve -as > files.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve -am > acceptmerge.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve -n > output.txt");
if( -z output.txt )
{
printf "perforce submit";
#system ("p4-64 submit");
}
else
{
printf "perforce submit and sending an mail to developer for resolve conflicts";
#system ("p4-64 submit");
printf "write an email to developers\n";
$sender = new Mail::sender {
smtp => 'mail.yourdomain.com', from => ' '};
$sender->MailFile({to => 'somemail',
subject => 'Here are the conflicts in files to be resolved',
msg => "I'm sending the list of files which have conflicts.",
file => 'output.txt'});
```

here we are trying to integrate using changelist numbers and resolve conflicts and send mail to users if still has conflicts in files.

Comment: command me correct command to perform integration for range of changelist example from 10 to 15

Comment: p4 integ //depot/main/...@10,@15 //depot/dev/... The revision ranges are documented here: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html

Comment: thanks bryan and could you please let me know how to find the files which have conflicts and redirect them to some output.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p4 integrate $branch1\@$chglist1,\@chglist2 $branch2 > files.txt
```

Make sure that $branch1 and $branch2 are paths that map all of the files in the branches, e.g. "//depot/main/..." and "//depot/dev/..." rather than "//depot/main" and "//depot/dev".  If they are not provided to your script in that form, your script should append the necessary wildcards before passing them to the Perforce command.

There should be no space between the file specification ($branch1) and the revision range (@$chglist1,@chglist2) -- it's all one argument.  The first argument is the source path with a revision range, and the second argument is the target path.

The "-c default" is not necessary because files are opened in the default changelist by default.

Note that the output will be a list of files opened by the command, not a list of changelists.

Comment: thanks sam really appreciate your explanation and could you please provide me a script to automate perforce integration using perl script.

Comment: Put backticks around it and a semicolon at the end?  :)

Comment: and after integration also I want in script to resolve conflicts and find files which needs to be resolve conflicts manually. as finding the files to resolve conflicts and redirecting them to files to let developer know about to resolve conflicts by them by droping an email

Comment: I am using below commands and but not able to find files which need to rsolve conflicts
system ("p4-64 integ $branch1@$chglistrange $branch2 > changes.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve -as > files.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve -am > acceptmerge.txt");
system ("p4-64 resolve");

Comment: You've mostly got the right commands, but if you're going to run "p4 resolve -am" you can skip the "p4 resolve -as" (which is just the "safe" subset of "resolve am"), and do "p4 resolve -n" instead of "p4 resolve" (since your script does not appear to be interacting with the resolve prompt) and then email the output to the user.  You might need to think more about how the user will pick up where the script leaves off -- that part really depends on your environment (do the users have access to the machine where the script runs?  does everything need to be in one changelist?  etc).

Comment: through script only I should send an email to developer about which files have conflicts still after integrate. so I want to know which command will show the files which have conflicts

Comment: p4 submit will not work for files which have conflicts...so I need to send those conflict files to developer.

Comment: After you've resolved all non-conflicting files with "resolve -am", "resolve -n" will show you the files that are still remaining to resolve (those will be the ones with conflicts).

Comment: thanks sam I try it out...appreciate your help.

Comment: sam could you please check the above perl script and correct me...